# Add one to a sql column

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have different numbers in a sql column. I want to add 1 whatever the number in that column is.

I work with PDO prep statements

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table
            SET streak = :streak
            WHERE user = :user");

$stmt->bindParam(':streak', $streak);
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);

$streak = $streak + 1;
$user = 224;
$stmt->execute();
```

If I use `$streak = 3;` or any number it works updates the table with the number. So the connections and the rest of the code works well. The key is how to add 1 to any number is in that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE table
    SET streak = streak + 1
    WHERE user = :user;
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that is ok. By the way, I do not understand why they gave us negative points